# Code inspection - Named Range Reference

Tags: vba, rubberduck

After running the code inspections in Rubberduck 2.0.11.2453, there are 4 Range references that get tagged as:

> Member 'Range' implicitly references ActiveSheet

The ranges in question are referring to Named Ranges.  Is it necessary to qualify a named range reference?

```
Private Sub RunORatio(ByVal TabNum As Integer)
  Dim Start As Integer, Cat As Integer, iMth As Integer, CurrentRow As Integer, Report As Integer
  Dim wsORatio As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, wsMacro As Worksheet
  Dim sMap As String, Test As String

  With ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsMacro = .Worksheets("Macro")
    Set wsORatio = .Worksheets("ORatio" & TabNum)
    With wsORatio
      sMap = "oratio" & TabNum & "map"           
      For CurrentRow = 1 To Range(sMap).Rows.Count             '<---1 here
        Test = Range(sMap).Cells(CurrentRow, 1)                '<---1 Here
        Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Test)
        Start = Range(Range(sMap).Cells(CurrentRow, 2)).Row    '<---2 Here
        Report = wsMacro.Range(sMap).Cells(CurrentRow, 3)
        For Cat = 0 To 12
          For iMth = 1 To 12
            wsORatio.Cells(Report + Cat, 7 + iMth) = wsData.Cells(Start + Cat, 37 + iMth)
          Next iMth
        Next Cat
      Next CurrentRow
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you didn't share your entire code (probabely too long) is `sMap` defined as `Name` ? did you set it to a `Range` ?

Comment: I did, the only thing left out are the Declarations...added

Comment: What is the scope of your Named Ranges `oratio1map`...? Is it workbook? You should specify the sheet in which the range is defined to avoid that tag, ie `Sheets("SheetName").Range(...)`!

Comment: do you have a worksheet with the name that equals `Range(sMap).Cells(CurrentRow, 1)` ? you have a sheet per each name in the row of your `oratio1map` Named Range ? I'm getting an error on the line `Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Test)` (because I don't have so many worksheets in my workbook)

Comment: Oratio1map is a range of cells I14:L16 on a sheets named Macro. Col I contains another Sheet name, Col J is another named range, Col K & L are both starting rows for a report and data.

Comment: The code works fine, my question is more about Rubberduck wanting the Range(named range) to be qualified...and whether it is really needed since it is a named range.

Comment: If you want, you can have `Dim Rng As Range`, and after `Set Rng = Range(sMap)` , even though it "pleases" the **Rubberduck**   I don't see any affects on your code.

Comment: That would limit the number of instances of the warning, but it would still give me the warning on the first one...which still leads to the question, is it really necessary to qualify a range reference to a named range?  The named range has a sheet name as part of its reference.

Comment: This is legit. `ActiveSheet` doesn't have to be a `Worksheet`, so `Applictation.Range` calls can throw if `ActiveSheet` is a `Chart`, etc.

Answer (score 10):

> Disclaimer: I'm heavily involved in the development of Rubberduck.

Consider this common mistake:

```
lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(1, Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

`Rows` is unqualified, and therefore implicitly refers to the active sheet and therefore `Rows.Count` isn't necessarily the row count on "Sheet12". The code *might* work, but it could also result in a subtle bug where `lastRow` doesn't have the correct value because of this, depending on the content of the active sheet.

Or this one:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SummarySheet") _
    .ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],["Date]]"), _    
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
```

See it? Because the `Key` parameter isn't qualified, the call is going to fail at run-time with error 1004 - "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed". That's [169 Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+Method+%27Range%27+of+object+%27_Global%27+failed). "Error 1004" yields [1465 Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+is%3Aquestion+%22error+1004%22).

Implicit references to the active worksheet are a very common cause of bugs.

---

Rubberduck's VBA code inspections are, like ReSharper's C# static code analysis, *hints/suggestions*. The tool is telling you that it's possible there's something here that *could* cause problems, or that makes the code less explicit than it could be.

Do you *need* to fully qualify *every single `Range` call*? Of course not - Rubberduck is merely letting you know that in these instances, `ActiveSheet` is implicitly being referenced, that's all there is to it.

You can always tell Rubberduck "look, I know what I'm doing", using the "Ignore once" quick-fix:

[image: ignore once]

That "fix" inserts a special comment (internally, Rubberduck calls them "annotations") that instructs the inspection to ignore specific results, while leaving the inspection enabled:

```
  With ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsMacro = .Worksheets("Macro")
    Set wsORatio = .Worksheets("ORatio" & TabNum)
    With wsORatio
      sMap = "oratio" & TabNum & "map"
      '@Ignore ImplicitActiveSheetReference           
      For CurrentRow = 1 To Range(sMap).Rows.Count             
        '@Ignore ImplicitActiveSheetReference           
        Test = Range(sMap).Cells(CurrentRow, 1)                
        Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Test)
        '@Ignore ImplicitActiveSheetReference           
        Start = Range(Range(sMap).Cells(CurrentRow, 2)).Row    
        Report = wsMacro.Range(sMap).Cells(CurrentRow, 3)
        For Cat = 0 To 12
          For iMth = 1 To 12
            wsORatio.Cells(Report + Cat, 7 + iMth) = wsData.Cells(Start + Cat, 37 + iMth)
          Next iMth
        Next Cat
      Next CurrentRow
    End With
  End With
```

These annotations have the advantage of telling the reader (future you, or whoever takes your code over) that there's something going on here.

Future versions will eventually support specifying `@Ignore` annotations once at module-level, to ignore all results of a particular inspection in an entire module.

---

Note that the inspection is under the *Maintainability and Readability Issues* category. `Range("DefinedName")` isn't half as explicit and fail-safe as:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names("DefinedName").RefersToRange
```

Which gives you the same range, *and* reads like it's actually pulling a named range scoped at workbook level.

Comment: Ok, I can understand that.  I've learned quite a bit from what warnings my code throws.  This one though is that the named range has the worksheet mentioned as ActiveWorkbook.Names("Oratio1map") = "=Macro!$I$14:$L$16"...just seems almost redundant to use ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Range("oratio1map") when the sheet name is already in the range.  However, if doing so will help eliminate errors or bugs, then I suppose I'll start doing that, and using the Rng as Shai suggested also.

Answer (score 8):

> Disclaimer: I'm also involved in the development of Rubberduck.

As @Mat'sMug already pointed out, the inspection is providing you information about the code.  What you *do* with that information is a matter of preference, coding sytle, etc.

In this case, the inspection isn't telling you that there is an error in your code, it's telling you that there is a potential that implicit object references will cause your code to behave in unexpected ways.  **The takeaway from this specific inspection is that you are letting Excel decide how to interpret which object you are referring to.**

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841254.aspx) for `Application.Range`:

> When used without an object qualifier, this property is a shortcut for
>   ActiveSheet.Range (it returns a range from the active sheet; if the
>   active sheet isn't a worksheet, the property fails).

The last sentence is the first reason you shouldn't ignore this inspection - `Range` without a qualifier will throw if you have a `Chart` selected.  This is the same reason why you should use `Workbook.Worksheets(foo)` instead of `Workbook.Sheets(foo)` if you are assigning to a `Worksheet` (this is actually [on the Rubberduck inspection wish-list](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/1925)).

The second reason is related to the first. As you correctly point out in the comments, "the named range has a sheet name as part of its reference", or rephrased "a named range can be assumed to be unique".  But it *doesn't* have to be unique if you have more than one workbook open.  Since `ActiveSheet` is ***always*** returned from the `ActiveWorkbook` at the time of the call, if the `Workbook` the code expects is not active, this code will either throw or return the incorrect `Range` (if the other `Workbook` coincidentally contains a `Range` with the same name).

Keep in mind that although the `With` block captures a hard reference to `ActiveWorkbook`, `Application` does not - and `ActiveWorkbook` can change during the course of your code's execution. This all ties back to the reasons why you should avoid using the `ActiveFoo` objects - *they introduce the possibility that errors will result from otherwise "correct" code*.

The solution is simple.  Just add the dot in front of them. That way they'll be calling `Workbook.Range` via the captured hard reference from the `With` block instead of `Application.Range`.

Comment: That makes sense, and considering that the guy that was here before me put a "Macro" sheet in every workbook...explicitly qualifying which workbook now sounds like a really good idea.  I guess I assumed that a named range would include that workbook somehow along with the sheet name.

Comment: @Rdster - Easy oversight to make.  You can see this by defining a range named "Foo" on 2 workbooks, then running `Debug.Print Range("Foo").Value` with each of them active.