# Use a cell value as Row and Column number

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to try and select the cell at the intersection of `MyRow` and `MyCol`. The current values are `MyRow`: 6 and `MyCol`: 4 which should select `D6`.

I can't get the correct syntax for the last line which is where it fails:

```
Sub SelectCS()
    Dim MyRow As Integer
    Dim MyCol As Integer
    MyRow = Sheet1.Range("a4").Value
    MyCol = Sheet1.Range("a5").Value
    Range((MyRow), (MyCol)).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

`Range(Integer, Integer)` isn't a valid call.  You should use `Cells` instead:

`Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Select`

Note that you should probably declare `MyRow` and `MyCol` as `Long` if you're using them to represent rows and columns.  You should [also avoid using the global](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41981099/4088852) `Range` object (I'd assume that this is for `Sheet1`, so it should be `Sheet1.Cells` or `Sheet1.Range`), and unless this is for UI you should probably not be using `Select` either.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply and advise. Works perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub SelectCS()
    Dim MyRow As Integer
    Dim MyCol As Integer
    MyRow = Range("A1").Value
    MyCol = Range("B1").Value
   Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer to add more value?